# Insert additional data beyond that is from the helper

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

If I have this form:

form---
username
email
password

And I also need to insert an unique ID that is generated.

This code will save the username, email and password in the DB. My question is about the codeLink.

```
$user_arr = $this->request->data;
$this->User->save($user_arr)
```

There is another (easy) way, or I should do something like this?

```
$username = $user_arr['User']['username'];
$email = $user_arr['User']['email'];
$password = $user_arr['User']['password'];
$codeLink = uniqid();

$user_arr = array('User'=>array('username'=>$username, 'email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password, '$code'=>$codeLink));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the values into the post data before you pass it to the model like so:

```
$this->request->data['User']['codeLink'] = unqueid(); // <-- this line
$this->User->create($this->request->data);
if ($this->User->save()) {
} else {
}
```

Things of this sort should be moved to the model, though.

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function register($data) {
        $data[$this->alias]['codeLink'] = uniqueid();
        $this->create($data);
        return $this->save();
    }

}

// your controller

if ($this->User->register($this->request->data) {}...
```